# Polo 1.9 SDI having problem to start at morning

Tags: starting, vw, diesel, polo

I am having a problem in the morning starting the engine of my Polo 1.9 SDI 2000. I have to attempt 2-3 times to start it and after it starts, it makes a strange noise and throw out smoke. I checked the engine heaters (all are OK). In the same day if I let the car rest for 10 hours, the car doesn't have trouble starting; it start on the first attempt. I also checked the oil; it has enough (I use 10w40). Any idea what the problem might be or where to go next?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I cleaned up your question to make it more readable ... if you feel I've messed something up, please just click the edit button and change it.

Comment: Perhaps a leaking injector?

Answer (score 2):

How are you starting the car? Do you wait till the glow plug light goes off before cranking?

I found that in my TDI, especially in winter, I had to cycle the glow plugs a few times and then it started no problems